# Why am I not able to drop postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, drop-database

I am trying to drop a postgres database. But I am always getting a

> There is 1 other session using the database

error.

I tried stopping all the sessions with this command

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='my_database';
```

this was the result

```
pg_terminate_backend
----------------------
(0 rows)
```

and then I used this command

```
DROP DATABASE my_database;
```

This is the entire error message

```
ERROR:  database "my_database" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

I am using postgres 12.

Comment: Are you connected to the database you are trying to drop?

Comment: Yes. I also tried deleting the db with pgadmin. facing the same error

Comment: you need to connect to a _different_ database. You can't drop the database you are connected to

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The same way you connect to that database, just provide a different database name.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. This worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Make sure no users can connect to your database (superuser privileges, superusers still can connect):

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE mydb CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
   ```
2. Force disconnection of all clients connected to this database (database owner privileges):

   ```
   SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
   FROM pg_stat_activity
   WHERE datname = 'mydb';
   ```
3. Then use your drop command to delete the Database (database owner privilege):

   ```
   DROP DATABASE mydb;
   ```

Comment: Hi. can you explain the first part more clearly. I am new to sql

Comment: The first part makes sure that no one can connect to your database(except the SuperUsers), so you are limiting the connections for your DB, its optional, but if you users keep using the DB and you dont want them to , then you can use it and restrict users from connecting to the DB

Comment: And afterwards, I suppose you have to unlimit with "ALTER DATABASE mydb CONNECTION LIMIT -1;"